Dell XPS 9310 upgraded from 20.04 to 24.04 now wifi does not work
I just updated my dell xps 9310, which came from the factory with ubuntu, to 24.04 LTS.
My wifi has gone completely.
When I run lshw -C network I get
-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:60531dc000-60531dffff
-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: d
       bus info: usb@3:8
       logical name: enxc28cc200661f
       serial: c2:8c:c2:00:66:1f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ncm driverversion=5.14.0-1052-oem duplex=half firmware=CDC NCM ip=192.168.226.149 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair


Also, for some reason my machine is running kernel 5.14.0 despite mainline showing I have 6.10.7 installed.
Any tips? I googled it and found people with similar issues but none of their solutions work. I'm a pretty basic linux user, so please feel free to give me the idiots guide.
Thank you
